# Multiple arguments on menu callback

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-routes

I know how to pass one argument to a menu callback

```
  $items['someaddress/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'title',
    'page callback' => 'some_function',
    'page arguments' => 1,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
```

I don't understand why the argument being passed is `$_POST['nid']` but this works. It corresponds to page argument 1.

```
function some_function (){

    $node = isset($_POST['nid']) ? node_load($_POST['nid']) : FALSE;

}
```

I'm now trying to pass multiple arguments.  `$items['someaddress/%/%/%'] = array(` and is looking for a code sample of how I do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use an array for `page arguments`:

```
$items['someaddress/%/%/%'] = array(
  'title' => 'title',
  'page callback' => 'some_function',
  'page arguments' => array(1, 2, 3),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);

function some_function($arg1, $arg2, $arg3) {
  // Insert code here
}
```

You should always keep [arguments passed to menu callbacks as an array](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_menu/6), anyway.

FYI: the behavior you are seeing is how Drupal's menu system is designed. The number corresponds to each argument being passed to the menu. 1 is the first argument, 2 is the second, etc.